# PHP Regular Expression to convert html entities to their respective characters

Tags: php, regex

I want to change

```
&lt;lang class='brush:xhtml'&gt;test&lt;/lang&gt;
```

to

```
<pre class='brush:xhtml'>test</pre>
```

my code like that.

```
<?php
$content="&lt;lang class='brush:xhtml'&gt;test&lt;/lang&gt;";
$pattern=array();
$replace=array();
$pattern[0]="/&lt;lang class=([A-Za-z='\":])* &lt;/";
$replace[0]="<pre $1>";

$pattern[1]="/&lt;lang&gt;/";
$replace[1]="</pre>";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace,$content);
?>
```

but it's not working. How to change my code or something wrong in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a few problems:

- Pattern 0 has the `*` outside the group, so the group only matches one character
- Pattern 0 doesn't include the `class=` in the group, and the replacement doesn't have it either, so there won't be a `class=` in the replaced string
- Pattern 0 has a space after the class, but there isn't one in the content string
- Pattern 1 looks for `lang` instead of `/lang`

This will work:

```
$pattern[0]="/&lt;lang (class=[A-Za-z='\":]*) ?&gt;/";
$replace[0]="<pre $1>";

$pattern[1]="/&lt;\/lang&gt;/";
$replace[1]="</pre>";
```

Comment: Keeping it all in a single string `/&lt;lang...&lt;\/lang&gt;/` though is a better practice. It's `112.03%` faster than breaking it up into two arrays.

Answer (score 2):

How bout without regex? :)

```
<?php
$content="&lt;lang class='brush:xhtml'&gt;test&lt;/lang&gt;";
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
$content = str_replace('lang','pre',$content);
echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: Of course, that's going to change tons of other stuff he didn't specify; `html_entity_decode` will change any html entity, not just `&lt;` and `&gt;`, and the `str_replace` will change any instance of `lang`, not just tags

Comment: I can't because it contain some html code . Like that

&lt;lang class='brush:xhtml'>
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;
&lt;/lang&gt;

So, I can't do like that.

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_replace is a lot faster than str_replace.

```
$str = preg_replace("/&lt;lang class=([A-Za-z'\":]+)&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/lang&gt;/", "<pre class=$1>$2</pre>", $str);
```

```
Execution time: 0.039815s

[preg_replace]
  Time: 0.009518s (23.9%)

[str_replace]
  Time: 0.030297s (76.1%)



Test Comparison:

[preg_replace]
  compared with.........str_replace     218.31% faster
```

So preg_replace is `218.31%` faster than the `str_replace` method mentioned above. Each tested 1000 times.